# How to prevent Tomcat from checking modified class files

Tags: performance, tomcat, tomcat7, profiling

I found my web app constantly use CPU even in non traffic time. I did a profile and found Tomcat background task contributes to about 20% of CPU usage in idle time. Thus I tried to set `autoDeploy` to `false`, however it still doesn't work, the `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified` method is always get called in the background processor, and it eats of lot of CPU:

[image]

Does anyone has any idea how can I prevent tomcat from running that method and get my CPU back?

Comment: I have exactly the same behaviour with Tomcat 8.0.24 on Java8 64bit Windows 7. It occurrs only when the Tomcat is run from my Eclipse IDE. When the Tomcat is executed manually (with the same WAR), there is no unexpected CPU load.